# How to install and enable a service in amazon Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm banging my head against a wall trying to both install and then enable a service in elastic beanstalk.  What I want to do is:

1. Install a service in `/etc/init.d` that points to my python app in `/opt/python/current/app/`
2. Have Elastic Beanstalk start and keep-alive the service, as specified in an `.ebextensions/myapp.config` file.

(Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-services)

Here's my `.ebextensions/myapp.config` file:

```
container_commands:
  01_copy_service:
    command: "cp /opt/python/ondeck/app/my_service /etc/init.d/"
  02_chmod_service:
    command: "chmod +x /etc/init.d/my_service"

services:
  sysvinit:
    my_service:
      enabled: true
      ensureRunning: true
      files : [/etc/init.d/my_service]
```

This fails because services are run before container_commands.  If I comment out services, deploy, then uncomment services, then deploy again, it will work.  But I want to have a single-step deploy, because this will be an auto-scaling node.

Is there a solution?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Nate, I have the exact same scenario as you and I solved it this way:

Drop the "services" section and add a "restart" command.

```
container_commands:
  ...
  03_restart_service:
    command: /sbin/service my_service restart
```

Answer (score 2):

You can cause the service to restart after a command is run by using a `commands:` key under the `services:` key. The documentation for the `services:` key is here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-services

Comment: Yep, but that still has happened before `container_commands:` has run, which means I don't have any access to my code yet...

Comment: What Jim is saying is that you can trigger the service restart by mentioning `command` in the service declaration, once you have the code available to the service. Similar to #3 in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done it myself, but I want to give you some ideas which should work. It's just the matter of convenience and the workflow.

Since it is not really application file, but rather EC2 file, and unlikely to be changed often, you can do one of the following:

- Use `files content` to create the service init script. You can even have a specific config file just for that script.
- Store service init script on S3 and copy the contents with command.
- Create dummy service script, replace the contents with the one from deployment with container command and dependency on the above command to the service.
- (this one is heavy) Create custom AMI and specify it in Autoscaling configuration.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried the first three of these ideas.  All have the problem that the service tries to start before the code is actually deployed to its final location.  So while, yes, you can get a script running, that script can't actually reference your app, so it's not that useful.   I'm starting to think that services are not the way to go, and a ```container_command``` that executes app code while still in its staging location may work...

Comment: @Nate: Well, with S3 there's no dependency on the deployed code. With files, the command is executed before services. So I don't see how it would not work, since service is running after commands. Do you have the details?

Comment: @Nate: Umm, but .config is in your project repo, and although it is not part of the application, it is part of the deployment. I'm using `files` to create cronjobs configuration file, and then invoke crontab against that file. It works just fine. You should look into `enabled: true`, it starts the service on EC2 instance boot time, although if your service was not deployed previously, there's nothing to run... What is the error log for the command execution?